# Image doesn't open in safari (404), but does in all other browsers

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, safari

I need to find out why some images output 404 error in Safari, but does open in all other browsers:

http://www.ciadastrancas.com.br/site/index.php?page=a-equipe

Just open in different browsers to reproduce the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Because you have % in the image name. This is the result of how Safari reads the file, there may not be an actual % sign in the file. Remove all accents and try to shorten the file name.

```
    1-Roseli-Monteira-equipe-Cia.-das-Tranc%CC%A7as--3cf49c5e95196d4cac9b0c6a1bcfc3f7.jpg
```

Don't use accents, percents, percents, or spaces in image file names.

[image: Author's Edition]

Comment: There is no % in the image. See: 1-Roseli-Monteira-equipe-Cia.-das-Tranças--3cf49c5e95196d4cac9b0c6a1bcfc3f7.jpg" Besides that, some images that are been shown in Safari do have accents and other characters. And remember, they all show up in ALL browsers, except for SAFARI.

Comment: See screen shot of inspector. Safari specifically does not accept any accents in the file name and all the file names are in Portuguese. This happens with French, Spanish, etc., Google it.

Comment: Hi Christina, I see your point. The fact is that the images that are being shown in the same page have the same syntax. They also have special characters, and they do work. See inspector image above. So, the question is, why Safari treats images syntax in the source code differently? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: This html works <img class="borda" src="http://www.ciadastrancas.com.br/site/uploads/_CGSmartImage/Lidia Rocha equipe Cia. das Trança -8452a30acbe9ce7be2ac8509579af4f2.jpg" width="72" height="101">

This html doesn't work: <img class="borda" src="http://www.ciadastrancas.com.br/site/uploads/_CGSmartImage/10-Maiara-Santos-equipe-Cia.-das-Trança-2131a75151db136099191f8f4d6a9c43.jpg" width="72" height="101">

Comment: Safari/Webkit doesn't support Non US-ASCII filenames in Content-Disposition h... https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20407

Comment: And since CalGuy's smart image adds a bunch of numbers to the image name, I've had to shorten my file names on all galleries to get them to show up in all browsers. So short names, no accents, no spaces, and I don't use uppercase either just to be safe.

Comment: Ok Christina, I better do that then. Although I am still curious why it works sometimes, and sometimes not. Thanks for your help anyway :)